# IList<T> Union doesn't appear in aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, list

In my asp.net website I am using EF and I have a repository base class with the following GetList method that is used in all of my BLL classes:

```
public IList<T> GetList(Func<T, boll> where, params string[] navProps)
```

When I use it in the class cs file like this:

```
public IList<Item> FilterItems(bool isActive)
{
IList<Item> items = GetList((p => p.isActive == isActive), new string[]{});
return items;
}
```

I can keep running other sql-like methods on `items`, like "Where", "Union", etc.

When I use `FilterItems` in aspx.cs file:

```
IList<Item> _items = FilterItems(isActive);
```

I can't run any of those methods on `_items`.
The Usings are the same for both.

Why does it happen? Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: You are certainly missing a `using` statement, probably `System.Linq`. Please post your namespace references

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - using *directive*. There are two uses of the `using` keyword in C#. One is called a `using directive`, the other is called a `using statement`. Using the wrong term for the former, and, specifically, the actual term used for the latter can only cause confusion.

Comment: I WAS missing  `System.Linq`. Stupid... Thank You!